# Nested list indexes with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

What's the equivalent of this in LINQ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++) {
    newList.Add(list1[list2[i]])
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: `newList.AddRange(list2.Select(item => list1[item]));`

Comment: You do realise that "doing this in Linq" and what you already have will essentially do the same thing in (pretty much) the same way. So why do you want to "do this using LINQ"?

Comment: Why do you care? Doesn´t your code work? Do you have any problem with it? Anyway doing this is linq makes it only more complicated and harder to read - unless you know how it works.

Comment: Thanks! It's a much prevalent action in what I'm working on and a clean solution such as Dmitry's increases the readability of the code, compared to my initial solution. I care because readability is a software quality metric and I think everyone should care about it.

Comment: "Readability" is objective and makes for a poor metric. LINQ **can** be more "readable" in some circumstances or less in others. There is no harm in writing things out long hand a lot of the time, in fact often this is the right thing to do. I'd say your solution is no more or less readable than Dmitrys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your newList and populate it :

```
var newList = list2.Select(t => list1[t]).ToList();
```

Or add the data into the existing list

```
newList.AddRange(list2.Select(t => list1[t]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get *all* `list2` items, so you have a `Select` from `list2`:

```
 list2.Select(item => ?)
```

and each `item` should be changed as `list1[list2 item]`:

```
 list2.Select(item => list1[item])
```

finally, you want to add the *entire* query (thus we should use `AddRange`, not `Add`) into a `newList`:

```
 newList.AddRange(list2.Select(item => list1[item]));
```

In case you actually *create* and then fill the list, say

```
 var newList = new List<MyClass>();

 newList.AddRange(...);
```

you can do it in *one go*:

```
 var newList = list2
   .Select(item => list1[item])
   .ToList();
```